# Good Amazon Simple Queue Service PHP Library

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

With all things being equal whats currently the more mature PHP library for Amazon Simple Queue Service? I'm looking for good Object Oriented PHP 5 code. What were your experiences on the library you choice? Any performance problems?
I'm building a system that needs to handle handing off messages to an unlimited amount of worker processes. A total of maybe 50,000 messages/data per day.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Last time I used SQS, I was using the [tarzan](http://tarzan-aws.com/) library. I also use the library for S3/EC2/SDB.